# Read excel svc and convert the resultat list to dictionary [Python]

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I'm several days searching how can I do this and I can't solve it. I see too much information about what I would do, but I can't solve my problem (sorry for my bad comprehension about it).

I would read the values from an excel and then inserted it into a dictionary.

For do it, I read from a csv Excel and insert it into a dictionary, I read rows and insert that into a list, when all are read I put the list into a dictionary, I have this file (Excel):

```
action  key
turn on     TO001
turn off    TO000
conect  CO001
disconect   DI000
plug    PO001
unplug  UP000
```

My code for read the csv file is:

```
def __call__(self, fileToRead):
    print("\n Now the output from a dictionary created from the csv file")

    try:
        with open(Read.ROUTE+fileToRead+Read.EXT, 'rt') as mycsvfile:
            dictioData = csv.DictReader(mycsvfile, dialect='excel')
            for row in dictioData:
                Read.list.append(row)
                print(row)
    except FileNotFoundError as error:
        if error.errno == errno.ENOENT:
            print ("File not found, please check the name and try again")
    Dictionary.setVerbs(self,Read.list)
```

On this part I have a problem, i would it read the values:

```
'turn on' : 'TO001'
'turn off' : 'TO000'
...
```

But it read:

```
{'action;key': 'turn on ;TO001'}
{'action;key': 'turn off ;TO000'}
    ...
```

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you over-complicated this one. If you're able to convert your excel file into a .csv one:

> ```
> action;key
> turn on;TO001
> turn off;TO000
> conect;CO001
> disconect;DI000
> plug;PO001
> unplug;UP000
> ```

You might be able to do something like this:

```
def csv_to_dict(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:    
        d = {}  # create an empty dictionary where we'll add the data
        for row in csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';'):  # iterate over DictReader object
            d[row['action']] = row['key']  # add data to the dictionary the way we want
        return d  # return the data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = 'path_to_file_here'  # here complete the path 
    pprint(csv_to_dict(filename))  # I've used pprint to have the dictionary nicely printed
```

Which will print exactly what you want:

> ```
> {'conect': 'CO001',
>  'disconect': 'DI000',
>  'plug': 'PO001',
>  'turn off': 'TO000',
>  'turn on': 'TO001',
>  'unplug': 'UP000'}
> ```

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I want, thank you too much!!
PS: nice nick!! :D